# How to add input tag by JS in ASP.NET Core in a clear way

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'd like to create and destroy input tags. E.g., in my service, payment methods can be set for each store, and the number of items can be increased or decreased by adding or deleting input tags.
I can add input tags and delete buttons by JS consistent with tags generated by tag helpers, but my JavaScript is agly and non-maintainable. Can I create a tag helper generated tag string, or can I take some good means?

My full sample is [here](https://github.com/phasetr/ASP.NET-Core/blob/main/EFCoreQuestionSO20230315/Pages/Admin/Shop/Edit.cshtml) and a JavaScript function generating input tags is as follows:

```
function paymentMethodTag(i) {
  return `<input class="form-control valid"
placeholder="a payment method"
type="text"
data-val="true"
data-val-maxlength="The field Name must be a string or array type with a maximum length of '255'."
data-val-maxlength-max="255"
data-val-required="The Name field is required."
id="${inputDataId(i)}__"
maxlength="255"
name="PaymentMethods[${i}]"
autocomplete="off"
aria-describedby="PaymentMethods_${i}__Name-error"
aria-invalid="false">
<button id="trash_${i}"
type="button" class="btn" onclick="deletePaymentMethod(${i})">
<i class="fa-solid fa-trash"></i>
</button>`;
}
```